# Create an array of markers Google Maps V2

Tags: android, arrays, google-maps-markers

Good afternoon. In my application I extract data from the database for the markers on parse.com :

```
public void ParseQueryMap() {
          ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("MyObject");
          query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
          public void done(List<ParseObject> myObject, ParseException e) {
          if (e == null) {

                    for ( int i = 0; i < myObject.size(); i++) {

                          commGet =  myObject.get(i).getString("Comment");

                          geo1Dub = myObject.get(i).getParseGeoPoint("location").getLatitude();
                          geo2Dub = myObject.get(i).getParseGeoPoint("location").getLongitude();

                         Location aLocation = new Location("first");
                         aLocation.setLatitude(geo1Dub);
                         aLocation.setLongitude(geo2Dub);
                         Location bLocation = new Location("second");
                         bLocation.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
                         bLocation.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());
                         int distance = (int)aLocation.distanceTo(bLocation);
                              if (distance<rad) {  // where "rad" radius display points
                                  myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(geo1Dub,geo2Dub)).title(commGet)                                   .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));     

                               } else {
                               }                                                               

                         }

             } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          }
      });
```

I want to create an array of markers to test its size, and if it is zero, then show AlertDialog. That is, I want to know how many bullets I got. Thank you for your help

**UPDATE:** I want to know how many markers shown on the map

Comment: and the problem is....?

Comment: As you are adding a Marker for each entry of List<ParseObject> myObject I think you are having myObject.getSize() markers.

Comment: myObject.getSize() shows the number of records in the database. I have plans to continue to calculate the distance between my position and the points of the base, there now I need to know what markers next to me, and what not.

Comment: I need to know the number of markers on the map

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
// before loop:
List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();

// inside your loop:
Marker marker = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(geo1Dub,geo2Dub))); //...
markers.add(marker);

// after loop:
markers.size();
```

Comment: how do you display them on the map? I can only display the last one out of my array

Answer (score 0):

```
List<LatLng> plots = new ArrayList();

//get your coordinates and add them to the list of plots
plots.add(new LatLng(latitude,longitude));

plots.forEach(plot->{
    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(plot).title("My 
    Position");
    googleMap.addMarker(marker);
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).